# Show position name in Joomla 2.5. module

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have the same Joomla module in two different positions, for example a top search and a bottom search. The "top" search is slightly different from the bottom search, so I need to check the position in the modules PHP code. If it appears on position "top" do this, else do that. How can I get the position name in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yoururl?tp=1   to get the position  ref http://docs.joomla.org/Finding_module_positions_on_any_given_page

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the position name in PHP code?

Comment: you can view the position in backend of joomla admin ...

Comment: I think it must be something like this, but $module->position doesn´t work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647730/can-a-joomla-module-know-what-position-its-in